# MVC 3/4 intranet application automatic / slient authentication with Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I created a simple app using the MVC3 intranet boilerplate / template.  Automatic authentication works fine for Internet Explorer on both local machine and when deployed on the server.

Chrome authenticates on local machine but on the server it prompts for credentials. Firefox prompts for credentials in both scenarios (as expected)

Server settings:

Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS7.5

MVC app is an application under "DefaultWebSite". Authentication on the application folder is

```
Anonymous Authentication: Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation:  Tested Enabled & Disabled
Forms Authentication: Disabled
Windows Authentication: Enabled
```

WebConfig main points:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

What might be making Chrome prompt for credentials? Other resources on the intranet don't have this behavior with Chrome, it just logs you in. Namely SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior for the Google Chrome.

Check the [Google Chrome: passthrough Windows authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/19914/) thread for more information.